Odd boolean expression
I'm trying to debug (rewrite?) someone else's Python/cherrypy web app, and I ran across the following 'if' statement:
if not filename.endswith(".dat") and (
    filename.endswith(".dat") or not filename.endswith(".cup")
):
    raise RuntimeError(
        "Waypoint file {} has an unsupported format.".format(
            waypoint_file.filename
        )
    )

I think this is the same as:
if not A and (A or not B):

If so, then:

if A = False, then it reduces to if True and (False or not B):

if True and not B = not B


if A = True, then it reduces to if False: i.e. the if block will never execute


I'm pretty sure that the intent of the if block is to warn the user that the extension of the file in question is neither .DAT nor .CUP, but it doesn't look to me that it actually executes that intent.
I think the if block should be:
if(not .DAT and not .CUP) = if not(.DAT or .CUP)

Is that correct?

Why not test it with some relevant inputs, then refactor as needed?

Maybe I need more coffee, but I'm struggling to imagine a scenario where this runtime error would get triggered. I can't guess what the original's author intent is, but if you believe that the intent was to error if the filename does not end in either .dat or .cup then a rewrite is in order. if not filename.endswith(".dat") and not filename.endswith(".cup"): feels appropriate.

This can be easily verified with a truth table: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra

Why are they checking for .dat twice?  That's silly.

It looks as though the intent is to check if the filename ends with either .dat or .cup and, if it's neither of those, raise an exception. If my assessment is correct, then the code is remarkably convoluted. It's also interesting to note that the tests are against filename whereas if an exception is to be raised it reports waypoint_file.filename whch might be something completely different.

Related to @jonrsharpe's point, does the code have good automated tests? Those are important before you refactor.

As you have two variables which could only have one of two values you can easily test each case, for example by doing
for a in [False, True]:
    for b in [False, True]:
        print(a, b)
        if not a and (a or not b):
            print("Condition hold")
        else:
            print("Condition does not hold")

which gives output
False False
Condition hold
False True
Condition does not hold
True False
Condition does not hold
True True
Condition does not hold

As you can see it does only hold when both are False, therefore it is equivalent to
if not a and not b:

However in this particular case you do not even needs 2 conditions, as endswith argument

can also be a tuple of suffixes to look for

therefore you can write
if not filename.endswith((".dat", ".cup")):
    print("Unsupported format")


As far as I see, for the second expression to be even relevant to the statement, the first one
Not A

has to be true. Therefore, A is False.
Therefore, the second statement looks like this:
False Or Not B

For the second statement also to be true, therefore B has to be False.
So it is a complicated way of saying,
Not A and Not B

, which by De Morgans Law implies Not (A or B)
